# Azure AD B2C just stopped working on monday after 5-6 months in production

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

We have been running Azure AD B2C for 5-6 months. We have done no changes to this and it just stopped working somewhere in between monday 27 april 15:00 PM - tuesday 28 april at 08:00 AM

We get an accesstoken but it cant resolve data from the graph

```
Microsoft.Graph.Core - Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

Its failing on this function

```
_graphClient.Users[userId].MemberOf
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();
```

Anyone experience the same thing? It just stopped working. There is no errors in the audit logs.

Comment: How are you authorizing these request? It feels like you might have an expired application secret or certificate somewhere.

Comment: We have checked this. And its not expired.

Comment: Please share a screenshot of the permissions added in the Azure AD app.

Comment: @AllenWu there is no changes to this permissions that has worked last 6 months. I have read about similar problems on different servers around the world depending on region. So i was hoping someone could confirm the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an Application permission `Group.Selected` that affects the calling of this API endpoint `/memberOf`. Remove the permission will fix this issue.

Comment: Please check the above solution provided by @Tony and see if it helps.

Comment: Doesnt work. We have seen this one. Have opened a supportcase. It cant just stop working =)